# How battery level is indicated in power bank

Tags: batteries

was actually trying to build a battery level indicator. looking at fuel gauge they all come with I2C interface. However is there anyway that battery level can be assessed directly and led indication can be provided on the battery level.

Comment: I expect there is.

Comment: Yes. You can monitor the battery level via voltage level or voltage level and coulomb counting or a variety of other methods, and then output via a simple or complex display of your choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously anything that can be done in a chip can be done with equivalent discrete logic.  You just need to replicate the functionality of the chip to detect the state of charge and convert that into the logic to drive your LED display.

[Here is a good link about measuring the state of charge of a battery](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_measure_state_of_charge).  It explains that two main methods are voltage measurement and coulomb counting.  A graph of voltage versus state of charge for some lithium batteries is shown below.

[image: voltage graph]

The problem with the voltage method is that some batteries have a flat discharge zone.  This is good for the circuit it is driving, but bad for being able to detect the actual charge state from the voltage.  The coulomb method gets around this problem by measuring the actual current into and out of the battery and and compares that with the battery capacity in order to estimate the charge state.  You can of course combine the two methods in the portion of the charge state where the voltage graph is not so flat.

As you can see, there is a lot that goes into estimating the charge state, so **you would probably be better off just using a low cost I2C capable microcontroller to read the battery chip and drive the display.**

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect to see full 5V supply charge controller ICs in these devices (there's enough manufacturers of those) that take care of all the charge measurement, voltage/current sourcing and protection, as well as offering a simple status output. That paired with (probably) a separate 8 bit microcontroller for a couple of cents that does the "user interfacing" in cheap devices.

More higher-end power banks tend to have more complex charge controllers that can also negotiate high USB currents, and these might integrate just enough programmability to light a few LEDs conditionally.